# difference between node* and node*& c++

Tags: c++, pointers

What's the difference between passing `node*` and `node *&` into a function? Don't they both pass a memory address? What do you actually pass when you use one over the other?

Comment: yeah this is pointers-magic http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

Comment: It's the exact same thing as `int` vs. `int &`. Or `double` vs. `double &`. Or any other `T` vs. `T &`.

Comment: @chris node* makes a copy of the address and node*& doesn't? that's it?

Comment: `node *&` is similar to `node **`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node *&` is a *reference to a pointer*, whereas `node*` is simply a pointer.

In that way, `node *&` adds an additional level of indirection and it is basically a second name for some `node *` (pointer to `node`). It is most frequently used for argument passing.

Please, take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The `node *&` notation is a reference to a pointer to a node object, allowing you to change the memory address pointed to by the pointer (through the ref) as well as the node value (through the pointer). Using `node *` notation only allows you to achieve the latter.